# Using jQuery delegate (on) with a check box causes huge delay in response - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Hi I have a dynamically create table which acts as a pick list using check boxes. I Want these check boxes to be mutually exclusive. So upon checking a box I need to clear any other checked boxes.

```
$(document).on("keydown", "#list_Instructors input.allocate",function(event){   
    alert("hit");
    $("#list_Instructors input.allocate").removeAttr('checked');
    $(event.target).attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

This sort of works but there is a huge delay between clicking and anything happening which is no good. I have tried all sorts of combinations with no success.

Is there is simple explanation as to why this is creating a delay.

Comment: When is the delay? Between the key press and the alert?

Comment: How much `input.allocate`s do you have?

Comment: If you want to have mutual exclusiveness it is more common to use radio buttons instead of check boxes.

Comment: btw, `event.target` is not generally the target of the delegation, use `this` or `event.currentTarget` instead

Comment: I can have update to 10 intsructors to choose from. The alert doesn't show up until I swap away to another page. Yes I have used radio buttons to actually resolve my problem for now. BUT the reason I wanted to use a check box was for consistancy of styling across a number of sub forms. Hence my effort to make these work as radio buttons.

Comment: @Esailija  ok noted I haven't experienced a problem with using event.target on other delegated events. Is there a specific reason for using this .... ah hang on event.currentTarget is for the current click. Ok will review existing delegations.

Comment: @codepuppy True but that's just by accident.. see http://jsfiddle.net/nTL4g/ for example

Comment: @Esailija - Ok I see that I will update all my delegates accordingly.

Comment: @Esailija - Can I Assume from your other comment that you query the value of caching selectors I have used document with delegate elsewhere without issue would you narrow the search for performance reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you bind **on method** for **whole DOM** which is **really BAD**.
So always try to bind that to the **closest div** (closest parent element) which your controls are exist.

And second thing is **always cache** your selectors for better performance.Like below

```
var dataTable=$('#dataTable');

dataTable.on("click", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

About **Event performance** from [**Jquery API**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) says like below.

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document
> tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must
> compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every
> element in the path from the event target up to the top of the
> document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document
> location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive
> use of document or document.body for delegated events on large
> documents.

Comment: Are you seriously telling me that delegating on `document` caused any kind of visible performance issues? Maybe if he has heroic nesting levels or thousands of different delegations on `document`

Comment: Ok so caching all selectors is going to be a big job! But If the performance improvement is as you say that that would be very useful. How did you derive your performance figures?

Comment: @codepuppy I got those figures from here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/

Comment: However this does not resolve the issue. Which ever of these excellent suggestions from yourself, Steven, Lix and Esailija I have used the only common factor is that pressing the alt key causes the alert or console message to display and the checks to toggle. I cannot think of a reason for this.

Comment: @Esailija I have update my post under Event performance.Please check that for what jquery api says.

Comment: I have accepted this as a very useful post. I think something else is going on in my particular circumstance. I have reverted to radio buttons for now as time is slipping away. I will return to this later. But some useful stuff learnt here.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be seeing is that until the alert box is dismissed, the code afterwards is not executed. The alert command is a blocking one.

Perhaps you can use `console.log()` for debugging purposes of this feature. This will not block your code and it will be executed on the `keydown` event.

Comment: Well I tried this. Once again I know that it is registering the event because the console message comes up but only after a delay. If I alt tab away from the page bingo all the hit's come into the console or alerts become visible. It's very odd.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$(this)` instead of going through another lookup. Also as stated above try to bind to the closest parent element if possible, for example a container div. With that said this should speed you up a bit:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '#list_Instructors input.allocate', function (event) {   
    //alert("hit");
    console.log('hit');
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    $(event.target).attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

But you should try to replace `document` with a container div or another parent element

Comment: @codepuppy Are you just wanting all the checkboxes other than the one that triggered this event to be checked? Also any reason for using keydown? IMO I would use keyup or keypress.

Comment: Yes I do. No reason for using keydown.